# Azure VM subdomain for each website

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, subdomain

I have an `Azure Virtual Machine`, for example purposes, say:

```
myvm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

Right now I am serving up my apps as `Virtual Directory` apps, for example

```
...azure.com/app
```

OR

```
...azure.com/api
```

I'd like to change that to instead be individual sites connected to a subdomain, so for above example:

```
app.myvm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

OR

```
api.myvm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com
```

Is this even possible? If so, what would I need to do to make this happen?

I've read this about adding a host header:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

But I'm not really a sys admin, so I need help on how to actually do this in `Azure` please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have those applications as separate websites and configure host header names to differentiate between them. Also, you need to have a public domain name to add those host records. You can't do it with cloudapp.net domain.
So;

1. Buy a domain name like "mer.com"

   Add a CNAME record named App and point it to myvm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com .

   Add a CNAME record named Api and point it to myvm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com .

   Deploy your App application as a new website on IIS and change its host name to "App.mer.com" in HTTP binding.

   Deploy your Api application as a new website on IIS and change its host name to "Api.mer.com" in HTTP binding.

   Profit.

Comment: Works great. Just wanted to notice, that after setting it up, it's important to clear cache of browser you're verifying the setup from. Without that, it may look like the newly created http bindings don't work.